# Why colon (:) is a illegal character if i want to create json array in ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, scope

I don't understand why colon (`:`) return a **illegal character Error**  if i want to create json array in ajax call.

Now i explain my code... i have a function with 2 arguments: the first `nome_file` is the name of javascript file where there's a multidimensional array what data about earthquakes, while second argument `query` is a string with parametres used to filter quakes inside js file (added with ajax call).

Quakes parsed will add in a empty array  `var array_padre = []`
But all quakes parsed will be `json` array.

```
    jQuery.ajax({               
        url: "http://www.example.com/"+nome_file+".js",
        dataType: "script",
        cache: false,
        success: function () {
            if(nome_file = "quakes48h"){
                var array= quakes48h; //name array of external js file
            }
            else{
                var array= week; //name array of external js file
            }
            for(var x= 0; x < array.length; x++){
                if(((array[x][1] >= dal) && (array[x][1] <= al))){
                    array_padre.push({ 
                        idserial: array[x][0],                      ​​​​
                        ipocentro: array[x][5],                     ​​​​
                        latitude: array[x][2],                      ​​​​
                        longitude: array[x][3],                     ​​​​
                        magnitude: array[x][4],                     ​​​​
                        milliseconds: array[x][1],                      ​​​​
                        region: array[x][7]
                    });
                }
            }               
        }
    });
```

Return that  **colon (:) is illegal character Error**

Why ? Thanks a lot....

Comment: because arrays don't use keys in Js, use objects instead

Comment: `if(nome_file = "quakes48h"){` is an assignment, not a check

Comment: and how i can create array with key ?

Comment: @bambam ohhhh damn :D

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs they're pushing an object inside the array, that's not a problem, per se.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs moreover arrays don't use keys anywhere.Arrays are evaluated based on indices.

Comment: You have hidden characters in your input. These characters after each comma in the pushed object seem to be causing the error.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca and so when i can solve this problem ? can you suggest me something? Salvami :D

Comment: *"salvami"* eh, pure tu aiutami :) on what line does the error manifest? Also, have you checked @evolutionxbox suggestion?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca ah suppose they are, didn't see the `{`

Comment: @Borja if you paste the code you provided into Chrome's Dev tools, it shows the funky hidden characters as big red dots.

Comment: the error is at the firts colon but i suspect that each colon could return same error... and where are these hidden characters ? after comma ?

Comment: @borja, yes, try with an hex editor, there's a bunch of rubbish after the commas. did you copy-paste the code from somewhere else?

Comment: i deleted all after comma but nothing... colon is the problem. I put "key" between double quotes but nothing....

Comment: @Borja check the red dots here: http://jsfiddle.net/bxus2pmq

Comment: @Borja try again, I did that too and it fixes the error

Comment: now is solved.... mhua ! So were invisible characters that blocked the code?

Comment: btw which editor you are using? I have pasted the object to sublime and it simply removed those characters.

Comment: @im_tsm i' using notepad++